# Using C to create a calculator

Tags: calculator

I know how to easily make a calculator that handles two or three operands with single operator (multiplying *or* dividing *or*...).

But how does one go about writing one that handles normal syntax and multiple operands, say `6 * 6 / 3 + 2` or maybe just their reverse polish notation equivalent `6 6 * 3 / 2 +`

Comment: Have you given any attempt on storing all inputs up until an enter event?

Comment: look at expression trees. here is a website that explains it about halfway down the page [link](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs225/s03/binary_trees/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a fairly simple recursive descent parser that can parse arbitrarily complex arithmetic expressions. The parser generates a tree representation of the expression, which encodes the various precedence/associativity rules of arithmetic.

The nodes of the tree will be operations (*,/,+,-) and the leaves will be numbers.

Evaluating the expression is then just a case of walking the tree and evaluating each node from the bottom up, until you get to the top which is the final result.

Google will throw up loads of examples of doing this in various languages.